# How to add directions on Google Map API v2?

Tags: java, android, google-maps, dictionary

I use the following code to add an overlay button on my map to allow a user to go to their current location:

```
map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
```

Is it possible to add a built-in Google Maps directions button as well?

Comment: You can try to add polyline methid http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap.html#addPolyline(com.google.android.gms.maps.model.PolylineOptions)

Comment: I am looking at giving direction, I have several markers on my map and user should be able to get directions. I do not want to implement my own direction algorithm as I am just a beginner, for sure google has something in store like they have for enabling a go to my current location marker on map.